# values found with macros are not replaced if inserted with copy / paste

Tags: excel, vba

the attached macro is used to find values with

xFind = Application.InputBox("code / word to search:", "search")

and replace them with

RepWith = Application.InputBox("Replace with :", "replace")

It does not work properly

if the values are entered with the computer keyboard they are replaced

if the values are pasted with copy / paste they are not replaced

```
Option Explicit

Sub cell_all_new_2() 'celle colonna

Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim FirstFound As Range
Dim xFind As Variant
Dim ResultRange As Range
Dim RepWith As Variant
Dim anser As Integer
Dim CellsToRep As Variant
Dim j As Long
Dim mAdrs As String

Dim Col As Variant
Dim avviso As String
       
xFind = Application.InputBox("code / word to search:", "search")
If xFind = False Then Exit Sub

RepWith = Application.InputBox("Replace with :", "replace")
If RepWith = False Then Exit Sub

Set FoundCell = Cells.Find(What:=xFind, _
        After:=ActiveCell, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False)
           
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then

    Set FirstFound = FoundCell
    Do Until False
        If ResultRange Is Nothing Then
            Set ResultRange = FoundCell
        Else
            Set ResultRange = Application.Union(ResultRange, FoundCell)
        End If
        
        Set FoundCell = Cells.FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
         
        If (FoundCell Is Nothing) Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        If (FoundCell.Address = FirstFound.Address) Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End If

If ResultRange Is Nothing Then
    anser = MsgBox("no occurrence found! ", vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "notice!")
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim loopCell As Range
Dim colDict As Object
Set colDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Loop through each cell and assign the column letter from its address to the dictionary (to remove duplicate)
For Each loopCell In ResultRange.Cells
    colDict(Split(loopCell.Address, "$")(1)) = 1
Next loopCell

'Assign an array from the dictionary keys
Dim colArr As Variant
colArr = colDict.Keys
Set colDict = Nothing

'Sort the array alphabetically
Quicksort colArr, LBound(colArr), UBound(colArr)

anser = MsgBox("found " & ResultRange.Count & "" & vbCr & _
         "<" & xFind & ">" & vbCr & _
         "in column <" & Join(colArr, " / ") & ">" & vbCr & _
         "code / word" & vbCr & _
         "replace with" & vbCr & _
         "<" & RepWith & ">?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "NOTICE!")

If anser = vbNo Then Exit Sub

mAdrs = ResultRange.Address
mAdrs = Replace(mAdrs, ":", ",")
CellsToRep = Split(mAdrs, ",")

For j = 0 To UBound(CellsToRep)
    Range(CellsToRep(j)) = Replace(Range(CellsToRep(j)), xFind, RepWith)
Next

End Sub

Sub Quicksort(vArray As Variant, arrLbound As Long, arrUbound As Long)
    'Sorts a one-dimensional VBA array from smallest to largest
    'using a very fast quicksort algorithm variant.
    Dim pivotVal As Variant
    Dim vSwap    As Variant
    Dim tmpLow   As Long
    Dim tmpHi    As Long
     
    tmpLow = arrLbound
    tmpHi = arrUbound
    pivotVal = vArray((arrLbound + arrUbound) \ 2)
     
    While (tmpLow <= tmpHi) 'divide
       While (vArray(tmpLow) < pivotVal And tmpLow < arrUbound)
          tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
       Wend
      
       While (pivotVal < vArray(tmpHi) And tmpHi > arrLbound)
          tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
       Wend
     
       If (tmpLow <= tmpHi) Then
          vSwap = vArray(tmpLow)
          vArray(tmpLow) = vArray(tmpHi)
          vArray(tmpHi) = vSwap
          tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
          tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
       End If
    Wend
     
    If (arrLbound < tmpHi) Then Quicksort vArray, arrLbound, tmpHi 'conquer
    If (tmpLow < arrUbound) Then Quicksort vArray, tmpLow, arrUbound 'conquer
End Sub
```

Comment: Compare the values of xFind and RepWith when you type in the values and when you copy/paste them.  Often when copy/pasting you can pick up leading or trailing spaces, line breaks, and other nonprintable characters.  You should compare the LEN between the two.  You can also try using the CLEAN function to remove them prior to searching.

Comment: there are no spaces or anything else in the copy paste

Comment: Type the value for `xFind` and paste the value in `RepWith`, then after `If RepWith = False Then Exit Sub, insert `MsgBox xFind = RepWith` and run the sub. What does the MsgBox says? @maxma62

Comment: the values in msgbox are exact but are not replaced

Comment: example :
write in a cell A10 = 123456

Comment: I copy / paste this cell in H15: H20
the msgbox is correct

Comment: but only the cells A10 - H15 - H20 are replaced

Comment: but not H16: H19

Comment: This is the exact issue I highlighted to you in the comment in your previous question. Please read my comment there and change how you loop your cells. And how does the title/description match this issue?!  @maxma62

Comment: I can't find the comment in the other question

Comment: @maxma62 Do a loop like what I did in the answer to get the column letter but this time do the replacement instead.

Comment: @maxma62 `loopCell.Value = Replace(loopCell.Value, xFind, RepWith)`

Comment: @raymond wu excuse my ignorance but how should I
proceed with the last function you attached?

Comment: @maxma62 Please read the answer, and I would like to highlight that you need to read up on how to debug your code as you would have discovered why your code is not doing what you are expecting it to be if you had step through your code line by line and inspecting the variables along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic to get the cells in `ResultRange` is flawed once there is a continuous range e.g. A range of `A1:A10` means there are 10 cells but `mAdrs = Replace(mAdrs, ":", ",")` will make `A1:A10` into `A1,A10` which is totally different (2 cells).

Replace this block of codes:

```
mAdrs = ResultRange.Address
mAdrs = Replace(mAdrs, ":", ",")
CellsToRep = Split(mAdrs, ",")

For j = 0 To UBound(CellsToRep)
    Range(CellsToRep(j)) = Replace(Range(CellsToRep(j)), xFind, RepWith)
Next
```

To:

```
For Each loopCell In ResultRange.Cells
    loopCell.Value = Replace(loopCell.Value, xFind, RepWith)
Next loopCell
```

Comment: i raymond Wu now your copy paste edit works

Comment: I don't understand why other cells don't change

Comment: how can i send a sample file if possible?

Comment: o.k. on  " .filedropper.com " ?

Comment: @maxma62 please describe what you mean by other cells don't change when your previous comment say it works. So did it work or not?

Comment: now the cells inserted with copy / paste the macro works

Comment: the other cells are not replaced

Comment: the macro detects the exact values but does not replace them

Comment: Are the `cells that are not replaced` in `ResultRange`? @maxma62

Comment: Are the cells that are not replaced in ResultRange?  yes

Comment: Actually, I might have found out the reason, try replacing `loopCell.Value = Replace(loopCell.Value, xFind, RepWith)` with `loopCell.Value = Replace(loopCell.Value, xFind, RepWith, Compare:= vbTextCompare)`

Comment: @maxma62 Please try what I said in my previous comment first and see if it works. Otherwise please provide the `xFind`, `RepWith` and what cells is not being replaced for me to reproduce

Comment: raymond wu your last change works

Comment: @maxma62 Great, in case you don't understand what's the issue - your `Find` method is case-insensitive while the `Replace` function is case-sensitive by default. Setting `vbTextCompare` to its `Compare` will make the function case-insensitive.

Comment: in fact in my file they are all uppercase

Comment: Please accept the answer since it resolves your issue, thanks @maxma62

Comment: now I have to post another change for this macro in a new thread